# Only displaying the last record of the array PHP

Tags: php, mysql, record

I have this Function:

```
function getLow() {
global $db_prefix, $min;

   //get latest week with all entered scores
   $lastCompletedWeek = getLastCompletedWeek();

   $sql = "select u.userID, u.teamName ";
   $sql .= "from " . $db_prefix . "users u ";
   $query = mysql_query($sql);
   while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

      for($i = 1; $i <= $lastCompletedWeek; $i++)    {

         $userScore = getLowScore($i, $result['userID']);

         $win[][week] = $i;
         $win[][user] = $result['userID'];
         $win[][teamName] = $result['teamName'];
         $win[][score] = $userScore;

      }

      $count = count($win);
      $lowest = 0;
      $min[score] = PHP_INT_MAX;
      $min[user] = $result['userID'];
      $min[teamName] = $result['teamName'];

      for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)    {
         if($win[$i + 1]['user'] == $result['userID'])        {
            if($win[$i + 3]['score'] < $min[score])            {
               $min[score] = $win[$i + 3]['score'];
               $lowest = $i;
            }

         }

      }

      unset($win[$lowest]);
      unset($win[$lowest + 1]);
      unset($win[$lowest + 2]);
      unset($win[$lowest + 3]);
      $win = array_values($win);


      //print_r ($min);

      //echo $min[teamName] . ' ' . $min[score] . ' ';

   }

}
```

when I call it from another .php file like this:

getLow($min);

I only get the last record....why?

Here is the getLowScores functio as well.

```
function getLowScore($week, $userID) {
    global $db_prefix, $user;

    $score = 0;

    //get array of games
    $games = array();
    $sql = "select * from " . $db_prefix . "schedule where weekNum = " . $week . " order by gameTimeEastern, gameID";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $games[$result['gameID']]['gameID'] = $result['gameID'];
        $games[$result['gameID']]['homeID'] = $result['homeID'];
        $games[$result['gameID']]['visitorID'] = $result['visitorID'];
        $games[$result['gameID']]['tie'] = 1;

        if (($result['homeScore'] + (($result['visitorSpread'] * -1))) > ($result['visitorScore'] + (($result['homeSpread'] * -1)))) {
            $games[$result['gameID']]['winnerID'] = $result['homeID'];
        }
        if (($result['visitorScore'] + (($result['homeSpread'] * -1))) > ($result['homeScore'] + (($result['visitorSpread'] * -1)))) {
            $games[$result['gameID']]['winnerID'] = $result['visitorID'];
        }
        if (($result['visitorScore'] + ($result['homeSpread'] * -1)) == ($result['homeScore'] + ($result['visitorSpread'] * -1))) {
            $games[$result['gameID']]['winnerID'] = $result['tie'];
        }

    }

    //loop through player picks & calculate score
    $sql = "select p.userID, p.gameID, p.pickID, p.points, u.paid ";
    $sql .= "from " . $db_prefix . "picks p ";
    $sql .= "inner join " . $db_prefix . "users u on p.userID = u.userID ";
    $sql .= "inner join " . $db_prefix . "schedule s on p.gameID = s.gameID ";
    $sql .= "where s.weekNum = " . $week . " and u.userID = " . $userID . " ";
    $sql .= "order by u.lastname, u.firstname, s.gameTimeEastern";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        if (!empty($games[$result['gameID']]['winnerID']) && $result['pickID'] == $games[$result['gameID']]['winnerID']) {
            //player has picked the winning team
            $score++;
        }
        if ($result['tie'] == $games[$result['gameID']]['winnerID']) {
            //player has picked the winning team
            $score++;

        }

    }

    return $score;

}
```

Thanks in advance for helping!! This is driving me crazy?

Comment: How can we answer unless you also show the implementation of `getLowScore()`?

Comment: I'm actually surprised you get anything at all. Your function doesn't even return anything. Besides, why call it like `getLow($min)`? Your function doesn't even accept any argument... You also probably get loads of E_NOTICE errors with unquoted array indexes in loops like that.

Comment: Sorry...here is the getLowScore function as well:

Comment: Gues I can't post it like that? I'm going to Edit my original?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not *the* answer, but this code is very broken:

> ```
> $win[][week] = $i;
> $win[][user] = $result['userID'];
> $win[][teamName] = $result['teamName'];
> $win[][score] = $userScore;
> ```

First, that adds **four** new rows to $win, a new one every time you use the `[]`, which I very much doubt is your intent.

Second, those should be quoted, so it is `["week"]`, not `[week]`. *Turn on PHP warnings and follow them*.

I think you want:

```
$win[] = array(
    "week" => $i,
    "user" => $result['userID'],
    "teamName" => $result['teamName'],
    "score" => $userScore,
);
```

You can make warnings appear with:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors",1);
```